# How to make action which will receive a parameter and write correct route for it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

I need to pass user_id, not logged in user, but user_id from view.

I am writing admin part.

I'm making post request using user email and redirect to appropriate page. so I want to make route something like:

```
     /:user_id/pay
```

to call pay action for appropriate user.

In my view I want to show email and link to this action:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <li>
  <%= user.email %>
  <%= link_to "Pay", some_controller_pay(user.id) %>
 </li>
```

**EDIT**

```
    def pay
    require 'httpclient'
    require 'xmlsimple'
    clnt = HTTPClient.new
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    credentials = {
        'USER' => 'payer_1342623102_biz_api1.gmail.com',
       'PWD' => '1342623141',
       'SIGNATURE' => 'Ay2zwWYEoiRoHTTVv365EK8U1lNzAESedJw09MPnj0SEIENMKd6jvnKL '
     }

    header =  {"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID" => "payer_1342623102_biz_api1.gmail.com",
                   "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD" => "1342623141",
                   "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE" => "Ay2zwWYEoiRoHTTVv365EK8U1lNzAESedJw09MPnj0SEIENMKd6jvnKL ",
                   "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT" => "NV",
                   "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" => "XML",
                   "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" =>  "APP-80W284485P519543T"
                    }
    data = {"actionType" => "PAY",
               "receiverList.receiver(0).email"=> user.email,
               "receiverList.receiver(0).amount" => "10",
               "currencyCode" => "USD",
               "cancelUrl" => root_path,
               "returnUrl" => root_path,
               "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US"}
    uri = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay"
    res = clnt.post(uri, data, header)
    @xml = XmlSimple.xml_in(res.content)
    @payKey = @xml["payKey"].to_s()
    @payKey = @payKey.tr("[]", "")
    @payKey = @payKey[1..20]
    redirect_to "https://sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=#{@payKey}"
```

end


PayPal say that some error occured.

I try to inspect variables, so I should put in view:

```
 <%= @xml%>
 <%= payKey%>
```

but id din't work, how I can inpect them ?

**In development log:**

```
  Redirected to https://sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=
  Completed 302 Found in 1193ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

So it doesn't insert link, yes ? How I can get ALL RESPONS info

How I can manage to do this ?

Comment: There's no view for `pay` because you're redirecting to another URL. To inspect `@xml` put `p @xml` in your controller and it will be printed to your console.

Comment: I tried put  p @payKey  and it didn't write anything - so link isn't correct, yes ?

Comment: Message from xml - The URL / is malformed

Comment: It was because I was using root_path) All is ok)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a `User` model, you can add `pay` as another [RESTful action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'pay' # or post/put, whatever is appropriate
  end
end
```

This automatically sets up a named route `pay_user`:

```
pay_user GET    /users/:id/pay(.:format)  users#pay
```

Including a `pay_user_path` helper for your views:

```
<%= link_to "Pay", pay_user_path(user.id) %>
```

In your `UserController` this works like any other action:

```
def pay
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  # do something with @user
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But How I can I do this in devise_for ?

Comment: Is there any problem when using devise?

Comment: I just don't want to create other controller. 
Can you tell me, how I can inspect error, I will edit question, ok ?

Comment: The error is either in your console or in `log/development.log`. So you don't have a `UserController`?

Comment: Yes. I'm using static pages controller. Maybe I will create  it)Please look at my question.

Comment: Okay, then just set up a simple route like C Cole suggested.

Answer (score 1):

routes.rb

```
match "/:user_id/pay" => "some_controller#pay", :as => "some_controller_pay"
```

some_controller.rb

```
def pay
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  ....
```